# Reverse SSH tunnel from Edge Device (Rpi) to EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, raspberry-pi, reverse, tunnel

I have set up a ssh tunnel between my pi and an EC2 instance.

Pi command:

```
ssh -R 7100:localhost:22 [Hostname]
```

EC2 command:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

Yields (Part Extract):

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7100            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13916/sshd: ubuntu@ 
    
tcp6       0      0 :::7100                 :::*                    LISTEN      13916/sshd: ubuntu@
```

The port seems to be open as it should be. I then execute the following on EC2:

```
ssh -p 7100 localhost

root@localhost's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@localhost's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@localhost's password: 
root@localhost's Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I cannot login to the localhost on port 7100. Does anyone know why this is the case? For reference, I have done the following configuration:

I edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config to the following:

```
- PermitRootLogin yes
- PasswordAuthentication yes
- AllowAgentForwarding yes
- AllowTcpForwarding yes
- GatewayPorts yes
- X11Forwarding yes
```

This is the complete sshd_config:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*    
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Sent the pi keys to the ec2 server:

```
sudo ssh-copy-id [awsHostname]
```

Set up the instances public to authorised_keys:

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

Comment: you already connected to EC2 so there is no need to copy keys from RPI to EC (they are already there). Now you need EC root's public key be copied back to RPIs (to pi and/or to root user). default credentials for RPI is pi/raspberry. You connection failures show that sshd at RPI is running so you most likely already replaced standard password for pi user otherwise sshd would refuse to start. I suspect that you just using wrong username to connect to RPI back. Try ```ssh -p 7100 pi@localhost```

Comment: It worked! Amazing thank you!! If I wanted to add another pi to say port 7103 it would just be doing the ssh -p 7103 pi@localhost?

Noted about better location for post - will do so in future!

Comment: yes. You are correct. But I suggest you to replace reverse tunnels approach with saltstack to avoid headache of tracking relation between ports and specific devices. Also your approach allows anyone having physical access to single RPI device to get access to the server and the rest of devices.

Comment: Actually every IoT/IIoT developer who tries to use such SBCs(RPI/OPI/BPI/etc) for theirs projects sooner or later starts to wonder about how to manage them when they run behind the NATs. I hope this question will not get closed as off-topic because I would like to share some good tips later.

Comment: Any thing I can do to ensure it is kept open?

Comment: /etc/ssh/sshd_config at server - ClientAliveInterval 10, ClientAliveCountMax 3. this will ensure that connection does not get broken

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean to keep this topic open - as in not been closed!